# JQuery UI Tooltip repositioning using SVG transform

Tags: jquery, svg, tooltip

I am using [JointJS](http://www.jointjs.com/) and specifically [Org Demo](http://www.jointjs.com/demos/org). My goal is to show a tooltip below the rectangle, but since these are SVG shapes, and their coordinates are shifted using transform and translate commands, my tooltip always is shown on the left of the base area (the left most position of the same height). I must shift the tootltip UI as well, but I don't know how to pass this parameter. I have seen something like this

```
$(document,"selector").tooltip({position: {
                    my: "center",
                    at: "right+200",
                    track: false,
                    using: function(position, feedback) {
                        $(this).css(position);                   
                    }
                }
            });
```

yet, this sample is using a general method for shifting all the tooltips equally. I need to shift each tooltip according to transformation.

How can I shift each tooltip according to a specified coordinate or offset?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('.element').on('mouseenter', function(event) { console.log($(event.currentTarget).attr('transform')) });` will print the transform values

Comment: I am generating the code for transformation manually, i.e, I have overridden the actual implementation and mine gets width and height as extra parameters. My question is am I forced to hard-code these values for every one of them? Can I use this value as a parameter for tooltip function?
a sample code is like this:
var lisa = member(550, 200, 'VP Production', 'Lisa Simpson', 'member4.png', '#2ECC71', '#008e09', 180, 70);

Comment: in other words, in the above sample we have at: "right+200" in which 200 should be replaced by transformed value of X .

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/) and setting tooltip to follow the mouse pointer:

```
$('[title]').qtip({
        position: {
            target: 'mouse'
        }
 });
```